# How to get this $\Sigma = [(I-B)^{-1}]^T \Omega [(I-B)^{-1}]$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

We consider n i.i.d. observations from the structural equation model. We denote by $X := (X_1,...,X_p)$ the $n \times p$ data matrix with n i.i.d. rows, each of them being $N(0, \Sigma)$-distributed, where $\Sigma$ is a nonsingular covariance matrix. The relations between the variables in a row can be represented as

$$X=XB + E,$$

where $B:= (\beta_{k,j})$ is a $p \times p$ matrix with $\beta_{j,j} =0$ for all j, and where E as an $n \times p$ matrix of noise vectors $E:=(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_p)$, with $\epsilon_j$ independent of $X_k$ whenever $\beta_{k,j} \neq 0$. Furthermore, E has n i.i.d rows which are $N(0, \Omega)$-distributed, with $\Omega := \text{diag} (|\omega_1|^2,...,|\omega_p|^2 ) $ a $p \times p$ diagonal matrix.  The model implies that

$$\Sigma = [(I-B)^{-1}]^T \Omega [(I-B)^{-1}]$$ How to get this implication?

It's from a paper, but it doesn't have any steps that how to get the implication.

The paper is this one:
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-41/issue-2/ell_0-penalized-maximum-likelihood-for-sparse-directed-acyclic-graphs/10.1214/13-AOS1085.full

Comment: Is there a typo in the equation $X=XB+E$?

Comment: @angryavian no typo here. But the background is B is the coefficient matrix (a.k.a. adjacency matrix). Thus B doesn't have any cycles. Say if $B_{1,2}$is any nonzero value, then we know $B_{2,1}$ must be 0.

Comment: "It's from a paper". What paper?

Comment: $\Omega$ is not mentioned anywhere except in the final implication. How is it related to $X$, $B$, or $E$?

Comment: @Gonçalo https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-41/issue-2/ell_0-penalized-maximum-likelihood-for-sparse-directed-acyclic-graphs/10.1214/13-AOS1085.full

Comment: @angryavian thank you for pointing out one typo. I fixed in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $X = E(I-B)^{-1}$. It actually suffices to look at the first row of both sides. We have
$$\begin{bmatrix} X_{1,1}, \ldots, X_{1, p} \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} E_{1,1}, \ldots, E_{1, p} \end{bmatrix} (I-B)^{-1}.$$

We know the covariance matrix of
$\begin{bmatrix} X_{1,1}, \ldots, X_{1, p} \end{bmatrix}$
and of $\begin{bmatrix} E_{1,1}, \ldots, E_{1, p}\end{bmatrix}$ are $\Sigma$ and $\Omega$ respectively.

Using the [formula for the covariance matrix of a linear transformation of a random vector](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113700/covariance-of-a-random-vector-after-a-linear-transformation), we have
$$\Sigma = ((I-B)^{-1})^\top \Omega (I-B)^{-1}.$$